# jQuery not working on url click

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to update mysql database on cliking url in **lecture.php**. But **update-lecture-count.php** is not getting executed.

Code in **lecture.php** is as follows

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" >    </script>
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();// i am also using jquery 1.9.0 in same page
$j('.reserve-button').click(function(){

var lec_id = $j(this).parent().data('id');

$j.ajax
({ 
    url: 'update-lecture-count.php',
    data: {"lectureID": lec_id},
    type: 'post'

});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-id="<?php echo $data['lecture_id'];?>">
/* lecture id, recording link are getting fetched from other mysql table*/
<a class="reserve-button fancybox fancybox.iframe more_info_btn" data-fancybox-href="<?=$data['recording_link']?>">PLAY NOW</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code in **update-lecture-count.php** is as follows

```
<?
session_start();
include("db.php");
if(isset($_POST['lectureID']))
  {
$_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['lectureID'];
$member_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

//code to update mysql database.....
?>
```

I am unable to understand, why `$_POST['lecture_id']` is not retrived in **update-lecture-count.php**

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing type with 'method' - type is used in versions prior to Jquery 1.9.0

So try to use this as your AJAX call

```
$j.ajax
({ 
    url: 'update-lecture-count.php',
    data: {"lectureID": lec_id},
    method: 'post'

});
```

Please refer to [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh... I solved it... Just answering here as it would be helpful to others too...

I replace

```
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j('.reserve-button').click(function(){

var lec_id = $j(this).parent().data('id');

$j.ajax
({ 
    url: 'update-lecture-count.php',
    data: {"lectureID": lec_id},
    method: 'post'

});
});
</script>
```

**To**

```
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
$j('.reserve-button').click(function(){

var lec_id = $j(this).parent().data('id');

$j.ajax
({ 
    url: 'update-lecture-count.php',
    data: {"lectureID": lec_id},
    method: 'post'

});
});
});
</script>
```

And it worked ...